# Request not ending in node.js (used to work)

Tags: node.js

I have this piece of code:

```
var app = require('http').createServer(function(req, res){
    console.log(req);
    req.addListener('end', function () {
        fileServer.serve(req, res);

    });
});

var statics = require('node-static');
var fileServer = new statics.Server('./');

app.listen(1344, '127.0.0.1');

app.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err);
})
```

It was working just fine, till I made a couple of changes, node gives an error, and when I went back, that error wasn't there anymore, but instead of work like it was working before the `end` event is not being fired. So, anything inside `req.addListener('end', function (){});`is not called.

And even if I run another node.js that uses the same event, is not being fired either. So is like if the end event of the request is broken. But how can that be possible?

Is not the first time it happens. Last time I ended up re-installing node (after try lots of different things). I would prefer to find a solution, so I can understand the problem!

NOTE: The original code include socket.io and other kind of connections, but I've just pasted the piece of code were the app is stuck on.

It could also be useful to know how to debug the problem!

Comment: try with `Node v0.8.x` or read Stream2 Documenation in http://nodejs.org

Comment: I can't speak to whether `fileServer.serve` works, but if you take out everything related to `node-static`, your code works as-is and the `end` event is definitely called. I remember having problems when we tried using `node-static` and you might be better off using the static middleware from Connect if that is indeed your problem. http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html

Comment: @InspiredJW I'm on v0.10.3. Are you saying I should downgrade?

Comment: It doesn't work without the node-static either. I'm going to give Connect a try anyway. But I think I should re-install node first.

Comment: @limoragni http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume or you can use `resume` for new stream API

Comment: i tried your code with console.log inside the end listener and it worked. remember that end is emitted when request finishes, if the underlying connection is terminated before request ends then it calls event close. end or close is emitted depending on how you send response See here http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_incomingmessage

Comment: @user568109 Yes, the code works. And it worked for me before. But for some reason, it stop working after a while, after some changes. And I even have another piece of code that was also working, that stops too, so is like if suddenly request are not able to finish. And I think that it going to work again if a re-install node, but I would love to know what the problem is, so I not run with it again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

@InspiredJW should get credit for pointing this out, since I had forgotten about it, but undoubtedly your problem is because of the changes in the readable streams. In order for the `end` event to get called you either have to attach a listener to the `data` event, or you have to call `stream.resume()`.

```
require('http').createServer(function(req, res){
    req.addListener('end', function () {
        // won't ever get called in node v0.10.3
    });
});

require('http').createServer(function(req, res){
    req.addListener('end', function () {
        // will get called in node v0.10.3 because we called req.resume()
    });
    req.resume();
});

require('http').createServer(function(req, res){
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {  });

    req.addListener('end', function () {
        // also will get called because we attached a data event listener
    });
});
```

http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_compatibility

Comment: Great. Is working now. What I cannot understand, is how come worked in the first place! I'm new to node.js I'm gonna have to read a lot to get things working. Do you know a good book about node? I know that Apress is working on one, but I would prefer to have one right away. Thanks!

Comment: I don't, sorry. I just learned node by using it. It probably worked before because you either had a `'data'` event listener attached, or you were using an older version of node.

Comment: @limoragni you probably upgraded node to v0.10.3 or higher and that's what caused it to stop working.